# What is the _messagebus user group and can I delete it?

Tags: user-account, migration, migration-assistant, group

I recently migrated to a new Mac running Ventura, and it looks like it migrated three user groups. I've figured out what the first two are and am going to delete them, but I can't figure out what the last one is. Is _messagebus something I need? Can I delete it? No user account got migrated as being in that group (or any other group, for that matter). Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [Hint](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7208204?answerId=28864664022#28864664022). Hint at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/970427/what-is-the-messagebus-user-group).

Comment: Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: Also, I updated to Sonoma because why not and the fink-bld and _messagebus groups disappeared on their own.